# SimpleWebRTC Server Side Authentication for Room Access

Tags: authentication, webrtc

I am trying to do some sort of server side authentication to allow only specific clients to join a SimpleWebRTC Room.

Right now, any client that goes to the SimpleWebRTC "demo" page can join the room.

Here is an example of my setup:

```
 ______________    ________________    _______________    ________________
|  Web Server  |  | Haproxy Server |  | Signal Master |  | Restund Server |
| SimpleWebRTC |--|  Load Balancer |--|    Server     |--|Stun/Turn Server|
|______________|  |________________|  |_______________|  |_______________ |
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how I allow access to only the end users I want, instead of anyone who goes to the page and guesses the room name.

I could create a room name that is so unique it would be highly unlikely to ever be guessed.  But I'm trying to avoid the "security through obscurity" method.

The "SimpleWebRTC Demo" page I'm referring to is based on the github project:
https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/simplewebrtc